Unable to Start Chrome Session in Selenium: "Could not remove old devtools port file" Error
I'm attempting to run this script in digitalocean server, it worked fine on my computer but not on the server.
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Scraper/example_code.py", line 4, in <module>
    scraper = OHLVCIScraper(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/Scraper/OHLVCI_Scraper.py", line 42, in __init__
    self._driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=self._chrome_options)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/Scraper/scraping/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/root/Scraper/scraping/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/root/Scraper/scraping/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/root/Scraper/scraping/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/Scraper/scraping/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/root/Scraper/scraping/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from unknown error: Could not remove old devtools port file. Perhaps the given user-data-dir at /usr/local/bin/chromedriver is still attached to a running Chrome or Chromium process

<!-- end snippet -->
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
class OHLVCIScraper():

    def __init__(self, coin, time_interval="1m", profile_folder="/tmp/chrome-data", sign_in=False, gui=False, one_record_per_second=True):
        # Inputs
        self._coin_name = coin
        self._time_interval = time_interval
        self._profile_folder = profile_folder
        self._sign_in = sign_in
        self._gui = gui
        self._one_record_per_second = one_record_per_second
        # Initializing the webdriver
        self._chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self._chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-crash-restore-bubble')
        self._chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        self._chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        self._chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        self._chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        #self.service = Service(self._profile_folder)
        self._chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
        self._chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={self._profile_folder}')
        if not self._gui:
            self._chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
            self._chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self._driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=self._chrome_options)
        self._actions = ActionChains(self._driver)

<!-- end snippet -->
What I've tried:

Verified that ChromeDriver version (126.0.6478.182) matches the installed Google Chrome version (126.0.6478.182).

Reinstalled both chromedriver and chrome again, installed the newest ones fom here (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable)

Installed libraries necessary for Chrome to run in a headless mode.
sudo apt-get install -y wget unzip xvfb libnss3 libgconf-2-4 libxi6 libgdm1 libxext6 libxrandr2 libasound2

Kill Existing Chrome Processes:


Ensured none that are running that could cause conflicts.
bash
pkill -o -i chrome

Python version:
Python 3.11.6
Computer Architecture: Ubuntu linux x64
here's a minimal viable code:
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
import logging
import tempfile
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def run_chrome():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-crash-restore-bubble')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        #self.service = Service(self._profile_folder)
    # chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
    # chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir=/usr/bin/chromedriver')
        # if not self._gui:
        #     self._chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        #     self._chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    print(driver.title)
    # driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_chrome()

